# Cannot select a value from a dropdown using selenium

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to automate one of the web apps using selenium but stuck at one point , there is an input field where I have to input some location and based on that location I get the output from google maps as shown in the following image:

[image]

now the problem is when I m trying to inspect the locations that are coming in dropdown by right click> inspect the dropdown goes away. This might be happening because the locations are coming from google maps api and not part of the web page I m trying to automate. But if there is any suggestion pls tell me.

Comment: May be you can wait for the element to be available. May be it's still loading?

Comment: Can you share a link, and the code you have tried?

Comment: Which _Selenium Language Binding Art_ are you using? _Java_ / _Python_ / _C#_ / _NodeJS_ ? Relevant HTML, code trials, error stack trace (if any).

Comment: i'm using java , code i cannot written anything bcz i cannot inspect at all into the elements present in dropdown , whenever i m trying to right click on the values present in dropdown the dropdown keeps getting closed due to which i cannot find xpath or any locator for those values.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your problem is you are unable to inspect the auto-suggest dropdown. If you right-click and inspect the *drop-down* list(or any one of the list suggestion), it will disappear.

So, to know the `className` or other attributes of the drop-down list so that you can automate it, do the following:

1) Right-click and inspect on the search-box. (NOT the drop-down list, but the search box which generates it).

2) Now, check the `<div>` *below* the search box element. It should most probably be your drop-down list.

3) If it really is the the drop-down list, it will contain `<ul>`elements.

4) Once you have your list elements, you can automate them. Check [this](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/25888/how-to-automate-a-autocomplete-search-text-box) for automating auto-suggest list.

Comment: yes so i already tried that as you will see in screenshot in the dom the one line that is highlighted(input id= address -search-id)  is the one which represents the searchbox but below it there are no elements or list

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not need to test google maps api. So you can do like this:

```
public void inputAddress(String address) {
            INPUT_FIELD.sendKeys(address);
            //possibly here should be some sleep =(
            INPUT_FIELD.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
    }
```

notice: in this case will be accepted first suggestion from list

Comment: already applied this like keys.down and keys.enter to select but i was wondering why i cannot inspect it and then using uft object spy i can inspect it

Comment: I think because this is third party application on website and all data in dropdown is received by request during type to input field. But all works if you try to inspect address field suggestions on google maps =)

Answer (score 0):

i was facing the same issue and resolved it by pausing the DOM.

Steps:

1. Inspect the text box element ,It will get highlighted in your DOM.
2. Now start typing, hover your cursor on list, may be first element.
3. Select "F8", it will pause your DOM, and you can see the details of List element in DOM.

Hope its helpful.